Is it possible to push a classless static route _with a metric_ throught isc-dhcp-server and dnsmasq?
We have an office on an IP domain of 192.168.10.0/24.
We run a VPN server on a domain 192.168.42.0/24 that allows the remote users to connect there.
Our office router is a client to that VPN with a static IPs of 192.168.42.10 (VPN) and 192.168.10.10 (office LAN).
W use isc-dhcp-server running on the VPN server to advise VPN clients to push a route to 192.168.10.0/24 through the office router.
Office LAN runs dnsmasq and pushes via DHCP to each office client a route to 192.168.42.0/24 through the office router.
The problem is that both routes are pushed with metric "0", and we suspect it causes a connectivity problem, as they may compete with physical direct routes.
Is there an option to push a route with a custom (non-zero) metric in isc-dhcp-server and dnsmasq?

I mean, is the goal here just to make this remote 192.168.10.0/24 route ignored on your office router and office hosts, or are you literally looking for a way to access that remote 192.168.10.0/24 site while your local site use the exact same IP subnet? Or is it not the scenario here? (What exactly do you mean by advise VPN clients to push a route to 192.168.10.0/24 through the office router? Why would your office router need any "advise" about its own local subnet?)

Besides, unless there's already an existing local site or so (and hence route) that uses the 192.168.42.0/24 subnet, and/or "office router" isn't (always) the default gateway of "office clients", there's not even a point in pushes via DHCP to each office client a route to 192.168.42.0/24 through the office router.

If it was just a typo, that there are only two sites (office lan and the VPN itself), then metric won't be relevant anyway, since the routes cover distinct destination/subnet. (Rather local subnet route shouldn't really be pushed by DHCP server -- they are normally configured automatically by the clients according to the subnet mask advertised, and should be direct route that does not involve IP forwarding on the router.)

No, option 121 has no 'metric' field (see RFC 3442), which means the metric is decided by the DHCP client software – and the range of metric values is host-dependent anyway.
If your remote users have a conflict between the "192.168.10.0/24 via VPN" route and their own 192.168.10.0/24 home LAN route, look into whether your VPN client has any specific support for metrics or overriding routes in general. (Although it's going to be a headache for the user.)
If you absolutely must, then deploy the "192.168.10.0/24 via VPN" route as two /25 routes (that is, more-specific routes), then metric should become moot as a more-specific route is always considered first.
In other cases I don't immediately see the problem. Your office clients shouldn't have a direct connection to a different 192.168.42.0/24 anyway (if they do, then it's your job to ensure all subnets in your network are unique).
